# Reacted user as channel name with Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm building a ticket system that whenever a user react's with the emoji, a channel get's created with him in it and the team that deals with the tickets. My problem is that when I want to display the user's name in the channel through the following code ``` await message.guild.channels.create(``│${reactor}``, {type: 'text',} ``` and `reactor` is defined by `const reactor = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);` I get the user's ID in the channel name. My question is if there's a way to name the channel `│User` instead of `│ID` (with ID I mean the user's Discord ID, not the actual text 'ID').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a simple solution to your issue, being that you're attempting to use a `GuildMember` object, instead of a `User` object.
At the time that I'm writing this (And it will probably stay like this forever), you're not able to get the username of a GuildMember, but would first of all have to convert it into a User object.
This could be very easily done with the following code:

```
const member = reaction.guild.member(user.id)
    const name = member.user.username
    message.guild.channels.create(`${name}s ticket`, {
        type: 'text'
    })
```

I'd also like to mention that you're not required to add `message` after `reaction` when you're trying to get the guild object! You can simply use the `reaction` variable you've created in your callback and use it to get the guild object using `reaction.guild`!